# How to convert a pdf to text on windows?

Tags: windows, transform, pdftotext

I have a scanned pdf and I want to transform it to an editable text format. Do you have some recommendations to do this on Windows? I was thinking about using Linux as a subprogram of Windows. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you work in Python, so a pypi package you might want to look into is [pypdfocr](https://pypi.org/project/pypdfocr/).  Essentially you'll want to use a tool like poppler to render the pdf and get the images from it (a scanned PDF is built on images), then read the text from the images via an OCR solution to get the text.

I have not used this package myself, so this is as much help as I can give. It should work with python in both Windows and Linux.